# Using SHIFT key in Flash app keeps triggering Windows StickyKeys dialog

Tags: actionscript-3, keyboard

Fairly traditionally, in my Flash/CS3 game I want the user to hold down SHIFT key to make their character run instead of walking. However on Windows I keep getting the "do you want to enable stickykeys" popup as a result. Is there a way to avoid this in Flash, or should I just use a different key... if so are there other keys I should blacklist as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's the option of disabling the key in Windows, which for me personally is amongst the first things I do on a fresh install. Under `Control Panel`, `Accessibility`/`Ease of Access Center` (depending on which version of Windows exactly) you will find a lot of the different options. Usually, the key to trigger stuff on and off (and whether it should be used) is hidden away in a seperate screen belonging to the function, meaning a simple button on XP or a hyperlink on Vista and above.

In my eyes the best course of action is to patiently go through the entire Accessibility section of your Control Panel, look at every screen/dialog, and just turn off all the stuff you don't need, which probably is pretty much everything. To boot, at the same time you will be able to make the list you need of key combinations to avoid in your game. :)

Comment: Problem is my users will likely have no idea how to do that, but I guess that's just how it is!

Comment: Unless your target demographic is very very small children chances are they already have it turned off. Using shift is pretty common (as we all know) and flash gamers are used to using it. It is good your thinking about such things but don't stress this one.

Comment: To amend/clarify my answer just a little: it should not be possible, or at least really difficult, to disable/ignore these keys (accessibility 'triggers') from flash. Flash is sandboxed, and these triggers are handled pretty high up in the OS as the functionality very likely involves fooling applications with 'false' information. (Example: using arrow keys to move your mouse around would give mouse messages to an app.) Thus, the best you can do is make a webpage with instructions on how to turn it off, and in your title screen display a hyperlink 'in case of problems playing, look at this'.